# What’s the point of checking msg.sender≠0 ? Are there cases where msg.sender can be null?

Tags: security, null, ethereum, solidity, erc20

In the [Tronix contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2#code) (a large ICO listed on many exchanges) lies this modifier which is used for all token transfers :

```
modifier validAddress {
    assert(0x0 != msg.sender);
    _;
}
```

I understand how a contract can write directly into the ledger that a token transfer is made from 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, but in that case, the msg is still tied to an existing contract or private key.
What does this means ? How `msg.sender` can be equal to 0 on a mined transaction ? (excepted the hypothetical case where a keccak256 hash collision is found)

You can find the complete Tronix contract code here : https://etherscan.io/address/0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2#code

Comment: As the mainet is launched, developers are no longer replying to token questions. It’s still hard to believe that such serious project similar to EOS listed on more than 50 centralized large volume exchanges and a volume over 200000000$ per day would have left useless code.

Comment: I suspect that if you use `eth_call` to invoke a function (no transaction) and _don't_ specify a `from` address, then `msg.sender` is 0. This is just speculation, but perhaps the developers wanted to make sure their view functions didn't return results for address 0 when mistakenly called in this way?

Comment: @smarx Invoking a function is done through a transaction of 0 value but containing data passed to receiver. In that case, `e` `c` and `v` doesn’t allows to retreive the original address when passed to ecrecover for verifying the signature. Though I’m not a `secp256k1` cryptographic expert and it’s possible to get a signature returning 0…

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. [`eth_call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) doesn't involve a signature, and it takes a `from` address as an optional parameter. And in the case of a transaction, you can certainly recover the sender, even if the recipient is a contract. (I think you meant `r`, `s`, and `v`, right?)

Comment: You're making a lot of statements, and some of them are true and some are not. :-) Do you have a remaining question?

Comment: @smarx : Ok ! finally found it : eth_call are executed only locally (relative to the JSON-RPC server not) but not mined on the blockchain, Correct ? In that case this is no use since transactions aren’t mined. Otherwise, yes, I mean `r`, `s`, and `v` : they are computed when you send a raw transaction.

Comment: Yes, everything in your last comment is correct.

Comment: @smarx : in that case, `eth_call` doesn’t writes anything. You aren’t explaining anything since the `validAddress` modifier if only for checking functions which writes on the ledger. **So I’m still not understanding how `msg.sender` can be null** The complete source code is here :  https://etherscan.io/address/0xf230b790e05390fc8295f4d3f60332c93bed42e2#code

Comment: You can use `eth_call` to call any function, but I agree with you that it seems unlikely the developer would be concerned with the results of those functions when called outside of the context of a transaction.

Comment: @smarx when I was writing `How msg.sender can be null` it was implied on a mined transaction on mainet.